# Simple batch files not working when using text editors

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm sure this is something simple I'm missing but I'm a complete coding noob.

When I write a simple batch file using notepad like

```
    sfc /scannow
pause
```

It works fine when executing. But if I write the same batch file using text editors like sublime or notepad++ it just opens the cmd prompt and keeps outputting lines of

```
    sfc /scannow
pause
```

over and over. Anyone know what i'm missing here?

Comment: Are you sure that batch file is stored as ASCII without UTF-8 prefix, etc.? Open file with Hex editor and see whether there are 2-3 bytes at the beginning or see Save As menu in your editor for encoding options.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the encoding to ansi and that fixed the problem.

Comment: @i486 You might want to convert your comment into an answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Changed the encoding in notepad++ to ANSI and that made the script work ;)